# How to allow null for foreign key to avoid NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have created an ASP.NET MVC web application to perform CRUD operations for my database tables. I'm getting an error

> System.NullReferenceException

when running the program.

The code is written to retrieve records from 2 tables: `Report` and `Member`. In the `Report` table I have a foreign key `MemberID` referencing the `Member` table that represents the creator of the report.

But reports do not always have a `MemberID`. Therefore I left the foreign key `MemberID` as a nullable column in the `Report` table. But when I run the ASP.NET MVC application, it throws an error and stops running in the following code location. This is the code I have in the `TestController.Index()` method.

```
List<ReportViewModel> repVMList = rep.Select(x => new ReportViewModel
                                                  { 
                                                      ReportID = x.ReportID,
                                                      ReportName = x.ReportName,
                                                      FrequencyType = x.FrequencyType,
                                                      DateAdded = x.DateAdded,
                                                      MemberID = x.MemberID,
                                                      Name = x.Member3.Name
                                                  }).ToList();
```

If I delete all the records which are nulls for the `MemberID` column in the `Report` table, the program runs without any errors.

Could you please advise on how to avoid this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string FrequencyType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MemberID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Table creation in SQL Server

```sql
create table dbo.Member3 
(
    MemberID int identity(100,1) primary key,
    Name varchar(255) null,
    Email varchar(255) null,
    Initials varchar(50) null
);

create table dbo.Report3 
(
    ReportID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ReportName varchar(255) not null,
    FrequencyType varchar(100) not null,
    MemberID int null,
    DateAdded date null,
    constraint FK_MemberMemID foreign key (MemberID) references dbo.Member3(MemberID)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your current schema and check for null in lambda. `x.Member3.Name` should be changed into `x.Member3?.Name` or `x.Member3 != null ? x.Member3.Name : null`

so all your code will look like this

```
List<ReportViewModel> repVMList = rep.Select(x => new ReportViewModel
    { ReportID = x.ReportID,
        ReportName = x.ReportName,
        FrequencyType = x.FrequencyType,
        DateAdded = x.DateAdded,
        MemberID = x.MemberID,
        Name = x.Member3 != null ? x.Member3.Name : null 
    }).ToList();
```